# alignment in new operator C++17 - Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, alignment, new-operator

I get an error for the following program in Visual Studio 2017 C++17:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    align_val_t alignment = (align_val_t)1024;
    int* p = new(alignment) int(3);
    cout << (unsigned long long)(p) % 1024;
    delete p;
}
```

> Error C2956   sized deallocation function 'operator delete(void*, size_t)' would be chosen as placement deallocation function

The program is compiled without errors in gcc-8. How can I solve the program in VS?

Comment: Try to get out of the habit of using C-style casts...

Comment: [`std::alignas`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas) and [`std::aligned_malloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/aligned_alloc) might be of interest to you.

Comment: You may also want to research "smart pointers".

Comment: @Yashas `std::aligned_malloc` seems to be undefined in VS.

Comment: You require C++17 for that.

Comment: @Yashas It is enabled.

Comment: Interesting, could be just another MSVC [insert word]. Try including `stdlib.h` and use `aligned_malloc`.

Comment: @Yashas `aligned_malloc` is undefined too. I use VS community 2017. updated last night.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/VP5Qsq.  What version does the compiler report itself as being?

Comment: @PaulSanders latest update of Visual Studio Community 2017, OS: Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: @PaulSanders in the link you sent, the `clang` compiler is chosen. The code has no problems with linux compilers.

Comment: Sorry, I compiled with clang rather than MSVC.  When I use MSVC I get the same error as you, see: https://godbolt.org/z/582hEw.  Looks like an MSVC bug.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in MSVC that was unfortunately closed as "low priority": https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/using-c17-new-stdalign-val-tn-syntax-results-in-er/528320.

Workarounds:

- Call the operator directly:

  ```cpp
  int* p = static_cast<int*>(operator new[](sizeof(int) * 3, align_val_t{1024}));
  ```

  but note that you also have to call the corresponding `operator delete[](void* ptr, std::align_val_t al)`.
- Use [`std::aligned_alloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/aligned_alloc) if you can tolerate the annoying requirement that the size be a multiple of the alignment.
- Use MSVC's non-standard [`_aligned_malloc()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/aligned-malloc?view=msvc-170). This must be paired with `_aligned_free()`.
- If you're on x86, use `_mm_malloc(size, align)` from `immintrin.h` (or just `intrin.h`). This also must be paired with `_mm_free()`, but is portable between Windows, Linux and MacOS.